# Codeigniter | repeated code in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter and the problem is I have specific code that repeated a lot in my controller, I need to put this code in one place and then call it inside the controller.

example:

```
 public function A()
    {
        something 1
        something 2
        something 3
        something 4

        $data = bla bla bla;
    }

    public function B()
    {
        something 1
        something 2
        something 3
        something 4

        for ($i=0; $i < ; $i++) { 
            # code...
        }
    }
    public function C()
    {
        something 1
        something 2
        something 3
        something 4

        if (condition) {
            # code...
        } else {
            # code...
        }

    }
```

every time I need (something 1
            something 2
            something 3
            something 4)
how can I stop repeating that?

Edited:
this is my "something" code:

```
$all_menus = $this->menu_model->get_all($this->getLanguage());
        foreach ($all_menus as $row) {
                $children = $this->menu_model->get_children($row->id_menu,$this->getLanguage());
                $row->children = $children;
                $data[] = $row;
```

Comment: will the `somethings` be static?

Comment: @Kisaragi I edited my question, thank you.

Comment: Put it in the your constructor

Comment: oh NOW you add that extra code :-) My example, and autoload the menu model in application/config/autoload so you don't have to call it in the constructor

Comment: but actually if this is for a navigation menu? then at some point you are going to want a view template, and you could do it there. really this is the kind of thing you don't want in your controllers at all.

Comment: Have you read the documentation yet?  CodeIgniter already includes a way to do this:  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class Something{

  public function A(){
   self::myFunction();
  }

  public function B(){
   self::myFunction();
  }

  private function myFunction(){
      $all_menus = $this->menu_model->get_all($this->getLanguage());
      foreach ($all_menus as $row) {
         $children = $this->menu_model->get_children($row>id_menu,$this->getLanguage());
         $row->children = $children;
         $data[] = $row;
      }
   }

}
```

In this way you have access to the data in every function calling myFunction with self

Comment: As I said, if he needs to do something with the values before using them, he can do the work in the __construct(). So nope, this works if the values are dynamic too...but, in the case he asked, you can see "something = 1" for example in each function with the same exact value, so the values are static in the question, that's why I write the answer in this way.

Comment: Then its easy, create a function with that code, and call it in every function you need it. Check the new code. In case you need "global" access (inside your class) to "$data[]" you can add the var "$data = array()" after the "class Something{" so in this way you can call the function myFunction and inside of it, you can assing values in the var $data, like $this->data[] = $row; and you will have access to that var inside A() and B() for example.

Answer (score 0):

A model:

```
    class Something extends CI_Model
    {

        function __construct()
        {

            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function returnCommon()
        {
            $common = array('hello'=>'world','codeigniter'=>'awesome','chocolate'=>'yes please');

            return $common; 

        }


    }
```

Any controller:

```
function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('something');

   $this->common = $this->something->returnCommon() ; 

}


public function A()
{

    foreach($this->common as $key=>$value)
    {
        // etc etc 
    }

}

public function B()
{
    $worldAwesome = $this->common['hello'] . '  ' . $this->common['codeigniter'] ; 


}
```

Comment: You're doing this with the Model?  Why not use a Helper?  That's why it exists:  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: @sparky thats why they have chocolate and vanilla bb :-) But no i don't agree, i think helpers should be for small functions, not things like navigation bars. Cue the person flaming both of us who insists it should be in a library. Also when he first posted it didn't include the extra code, so i was responding to a more general question.

Comment: It does not fit this very well:  [_"Typically your model classes will contain functions that help you retrieve, insert, and update information in your database."_](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html)

Comment: @sparky Its either going into a model, a library, a helper, or a config. I use models for a lot of tasks that are specific to the application. That is a personal preference.